# Proper command execution for Control access in system

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I hope my title fits to my question. Good Evening

I have a form with 2 datagridview the first one contains data from my Inventory System and the 2nd contains my controls name.

The 2nd Datagridview contains data that looks like this.

[image]

and I have a controls named command button in my form and it looks like this

[image]

so if I will relate each of them it will look like this.

[image]

The column `ControlName` contains the name of all my command button and the column `Access` will act as `Button Name.Enabled = True/False` for example the Highlighted blue one `ControlName = Review` and `Access = True` so it means `Review.Enabled = True`

Now i have the 1st datagridview and it looks like this.

[image]

Now every time i will click a row on the 1st datagridview the buttons above also will enabled depends on the criteria on the 6 column (5 in datagridview column) for further explanation here is the code for that.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    If DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value = "Reviewed" Then
        Review.Enabled = True
        View.Enabled = True
        CanceledPR.Enabled = True
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value = "Unposted" Then
        Review.Enabled = True
        View.Enabled = True
        CanceledPR.Enabled = True
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value = "Partially Selected" Then
        Review.Enabled = False
        View.Enabled = True
        CanceledPR.Enabled = False
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value = "Fully Selected" Then
        Review.Enabled = False
        View.Enabled = True
        CanceledPR.Enabled = False
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value = "Cancelled PR" Then
        Review.Enabled = False
        View.Enabled = True
        CanceledPR.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

and here is the code in enabling command button based on 2nd datagridview

```
            Dim Enable As Boolean
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                Enable = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("Access").Value)
                Me.Controls(row.Cells("ControlName").Value.ToString()).Enabled = Enable
Next
```

Now here is my question, How can I combine them? I mean do the procedure when clicking rows on the 1st datagridview and still follow the privilege in controls in the 2nd datagridview.

last time i change the value of `Access` column in the 2nd DGV to `true` and do the proper code execution in the 1st DGV and the output is all button has been enabled. i try to put both code in the Datagridview1_Click.

I tried on this code

```
Private Function EnableByPermission(ByVal buttonName As String) As Boolean
        Dim Enable As Boolean = False

        ' Look over the Enumerable collection of Rows the one where the
        ' cell for ControlName contains the button name required
        Dim row = DataGridView2.Rows _
                  .Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
                  .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) _
                      x.Cells("ControlName").Value.ToString = buttonName)


        ' If we found it then return the boolean value for the Access column      
        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            Enable = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("Access").Value)
        End If
        Return Enable
    End Function
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index


        If DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value =  "Reviewed" Then
            Review.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("Review")
            View.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("View")
            CanceledPR.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("CanceledPR")
        ElseIf DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value = "Unposted" Then
            Review.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("Review")
            View.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("View")
            CanceledPR.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("CanceledPR")
        End If
    End Sub
```

and click the row "Unposted" and the button `Review` has been Enabled but when i click the row "Reviewed" the button `Review` still enable whick suppost to be disbale

I hope someone helps me TY

Comment: But who has the last word in this context? The settings of the Access columns or the settings hard coded as consequence of the value in the Status column?

Comment: i tried the status column code first before the access but it didnt work

Comment: @Steve why did u delete the code?

Comment: Noted on that sir willing to wait

Comment: Updated the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform the code that looks at the "Access" column in a function that returns a Boolean according to your "permissions" settings

```
Private Function  EnableByPermission(buttonName as string) as Boolean
    Dim Enable As Boolean = False

    ' Look over the Enumerable collection of Rows the one where the
    ' cell for ControlName contains the button name required
    Dim row = DataGridView2.Rows _
              .Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
              .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) _ 
                  x.Cells("ControlName") = buttonName) 


    ' If we found it then return the boolean value for the Access column      
    If row IsNot Nothing Then
        Enable = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("Access").Value)
    End If
    Return Enable
End Function

...

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim status as String = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value.ToString()

    ' Logical AND between the predefined value for the Status column and
    ' the return value of the Function EnableByPermission. 
    ' In this way the buttons are enabled only if both columns agree on the 
    ' enabled status of the button
    If status = "Reviewed" Then
        Review.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("Review")
        View.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("View")
        CanceledPR.Enabled = True And EnableByPermission("CanceledPR")
    Else If status = "Unposted" Then
        .... and so on....
```

Comment: what do u think the first code will come the status or the access??

Comment: sir it has an error of overload resolution failed in the function

Comment: pls check the last part of my post

Comment: What is the value in the Column "Access" when the event DataGridView1_CellClick is raised? According to your images above and the code for the "Unposted" status the result is True AND True and, of course, this result in a Review button enabled.

Comment: when datagridview1 is clicked the command will based on what button will raised depends on the status and after that access will check. just think something that a normal procedure will still continue but this time it has access privilage

Comment: TY for the code, already fixed, there`s only a problem in my conditional statement